# How to Load Relational Database Format Data into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I want to load some sample Relational Database Format Data  to POSTGIS. Are there any tools or methods to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably refer to [this NAVTEQ format](http://sampledata.navteq.com/site/global/developer_resources/sample_data/p_sample_data.jsp#rdf). There is link for instructions to loading a sample of such data in PostgreSQL [here](http://sampledata.navteq.com/site/global/products_licensing/navdataformats/rdf/p_rdf.jsp), but requires logging in, I think the registration is free, so you can try that.